# Category tree from database. Make clickable only cat_parent_id> 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have this script to get the category tree from the database and show it in a html SELECT

```
function CategoryTree(&$output=null, $cat_parent_id=0, $indent=null){

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test-2", 'root', '');

try {
// prepare select query
$query = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM category WHERE cat_parent_id=:parentid";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);

// this is the first question mark
$stmt->bindParam(2, $id);

// execute our query
$stmt->execute(array( 'parentid' => $cat_parent_id));

// show the categories one by one
while($c = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $output .= '<option value=' . $c['cat_id'] . '>' . $indent . $c['cat_name'] . "</option>\n";
    if($c['cat_id'] != $cat_parent_id){

        CategoryTree($output, $c['cat_id'], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
}
// return the list of categories
return $output;
 }
  // show error
    catch(PDOException $exception){
   die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
   }
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<td><select name="category" id="category" required="">
 <option value='0'>Select the category</option>

 <?php

   echo CategoryTree();
 ?>  
     </select>
  </td>
```

I would like that when cat_parent_id = 0 in the html select, cat_name is not clickable, just show it as bold. 
While if cat_parent_id> 0 remain selectable into the html select.

How can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: not directly related to your question, but I would move opening the database connection outside the function, otherwise you open a new connection for every tree entry...

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. One thing at a time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the following code :

```
while($c = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $output .= '<option value=' . $c['cat_id'] . '>' . $indent . $c['cat_name'] . "</option>\n";
    if($c['cat_id'] != $cat_parent_id){

        CategoryTree($output, $c['cat_id'], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
}
```

to :

```
while($c = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$disable= "";
if($cat_parent_id==0 ){
        $disable= 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    $output .= '<option  '. $disable.'  value=' . $c['cat_id'] . '>' . $indent . $c['cat_name'] . "</option>\n";
    if($c['cat_id'] != $cat_parent_id){

        CategoryTree($output, $c['cat_id'], $indent . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    }
}
```